# What is the difference between RFLP and DNA fingerprinting?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, snp

Is RFLP (restriction fragment length polymorphism) analysis the same as DNA fingerprinting? I looked for information online and I don't understand the difference.

Comment: What *do* you understand about each concept, and where exactly are you stuck? In particular, have you read through the Wikipedia article on [DNA profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_profiling), the very first result when googling `DNA fingerprinting`?